# Executing db2 command through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, su

trying to ssh to another system then perform db2 commands however using 'su db2admin -c' does not seem to work, although it works for normal system commands ..

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p 'passw0rd' ssh root@server.com "su db2admin -c 'db2text start'"
```

this is the output ..

```
rob@laptop:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh
bash: db2text: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PATH is not getting updated to the normal root users PATH. Either specify the full path to db2text or add a dash (-) before the username to reload the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess and say that root doesn't have any of the db2 stuff in hi path.
And since you're using *su db2admin* rather than *su - db2admin* db2admin inherits
root's environment.  Try with that extra - thrown in.

That all said: why on earth aren't you connecting w/ passwordless keys as db2admin?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked ..

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p 'passw0rd' ssh root@server.com "su db2admin -c '~/sqllib/bin/db2text start'"
```

But problem is db2 path may change, better to use Eric's answer.